# How to push array multidimensional in javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to push an array multidimensional using javascript. I need this to set dataset for chartJs.
I want the result like this :

```
datasets: [{
    label: 'Manajemen Informatika',
    data: [100, 105, 203, 160, 200],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(189, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(189, 99, 132, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1
}, {
    label: 'Teknik Informatika',
    data: [105, 100, 250, 170, 190],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(94, 126, 189, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(94, 126, 189, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1
}, {
    label: 'Sistem Informasi',
    data: [90, 120, 225, 185, 200],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(72, 189, 122, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(72, 189, 122, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1
}]
```

Comment: What is your existing data structure and what does your code look like at the moment?

Comment: Your desired result isn't a multidimensional array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired dataset look like an array of the objects, where every data within the curly braces is object.
So if you want to put multidimensional array in JS, create each object in a variable, add data to that and then push that to the array. Like

```
let arr = [];
let obj1 = {}; //add data to this object
arr.push(obj1);
let obj2 = {}; //add data to this object
arr.push(obj2);
.
.
.
let objn = {}; //add data to this object
arr.push(objn)
```

Comment: can it created by for looping? i want it dynamically from database.

Comment: Yes you can loop also.

Comment: Use "for" to the last object of the database and push that to array, you don't need to create separate variable for each of your data. If you are fetching it from database, then fetch each row as object and push it to array, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to give the definition for your input first. The result you wrote is just a Array of Object. The multidimensional array should like this one:

```
const multidimensionalArray = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [12,13,15,16],
  [17,2,31,]
]
```

For you question I assume you receive data from backend :

```
const responseData = [{data1, data2, data3, data4}]

const result = responseData.map(item => {
   /// Do some manipulate data here
   const stypingObj = item.type ? styling1 : styling2 
   const valueArray = item.valueData  // You can manipulate value also
   return chartData = { ...item. data: valueArray, ...stylingObj }
})
```

Then it return your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

No worries, this architecture is a bit messy, always hard to write and read.

You should use something like:

```js
var d = {
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Manajemen Informatika',
      data: [100, 105, 203, 160, 200],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(189, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(189, 99, 132, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
}


d.datasets.push(
  {
    label: 'Sistem Informasi',
    data: [90, 120, 225, 185, 200],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(72, 189, 122, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(72, 189, 122, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1
  }
)

// Read a particular value
console.log(d.datasets[1].label)

// Whole object
console.log(d)
```

We are not supposed to write an object by hand ourself, but *chart.js* is made like that, forcing every configuration as such nested in objects, and it become worst using plugins you have to pass functions there as well, this makes messy scripts.

Side note, would recommend to avoid using chart.js altogether, [for different reasons](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To How to push array multidimensional in javascript

```
var PushToArray = { };
PushToArray.productID = productID;
PushToArray.itemColorTitle = itemProductTitle;
PushToArray.itemColorPath = itemProduct;
cookie_value_add.push(PushToArray);
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.